# "com.springsource" prefix on artifact/module causing conflicts

Tags: spring, maven, ivy

I have a dependency on my project like this:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework"
            name="org.springframework.web.servlet"
            rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
```

And it wants to pull things like this:

```
org.apache.commons#com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging;1.1.1
```

which causes issues with other libraries that use a newer version of commons-logging. So I work around it by excluding it like this:

```
<exclude org="org.apache.commons"
         module="com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging" />
```

but having to do that kind of defeats the purpose of the conflict management Ivy has built-in. Is there a better way to handle this, or do I have to track down all the potential conflicts manually?

**Disclaimer:** I'm pretty new to Ivy and dependency management, so I have no idea if this concept extends into the Maven world as well. If not, I apologize for the false tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the [EBR repositories](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q7) in your `ivysettings.xml` file.
You get those `com.springsource` dependencies because all the libraries in EBR are valid OSGi bundles and SpringSource transformed normal jars in bundles by prefixing the bundle names with `com.springsource`.

Also, I'm assuming your project doesn't make use of an OSGi container and you don't actually need OSGi bundles in your project. To get back to resolving normal jars and not OSGi bundles you need not to use the EBR repositories.

In your `ivysettings.xml` comment the resolvers that point to EBR repositories, for example:

```xml
<!-- <resolvers>
    <chain name="chained">
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
    </chain>
</resolvers> -->
```

And replace those with the [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver:

```
<settings defaultResolver="central"/>
<resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
</resolvers>
```

Also, you need to change any dependency that, initially, was taken from EBR repositories to the format the usual Maven central repository has. For example, your dependency on `org.springframework.web.servlet` needs to be changed in `ivy.xml` to:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework"
            name="spring-web"
            rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
```

With the changes above, Ivy will resolve the dependencies from [Maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/3.1.2.RELEASE), as well.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you! Why doesn't spring make this less confusing by making the org something like `org.springframework.osgi`?

Comment: Because there's no source code difference between `org.springframework.web.servlet` and `spring-mvc` jars. They are identical with the only difference at the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, which has OSGi headers.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it would be better to have them in a different package, though, so that people (like me) that are just searching for their dependencies don't get those mixed up. Thanks again for your help!